# How to Store Each Object in Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

What I would like to do is to process JSON data and store each object after getting out of the `for` loop. However, the `obj` gets updated every iteration, so the `objectArray` holds only David's information in each element in it. I would like the `objArray` to hold each of the processed JSON objects (screenshot below). The JSON process is to store search a userId and name and store them in the `objectArray`. Could someone help me figure out how I could store each object in the `objectArray`? Thank you in advance.

```js
const obj = {};
var objectArray = [];
var data = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "John",
        "phoneNumber": "123-456-6789"
    },
    {
        "userId": "345",
        "name": "Summer",
        "phoneNumber": "535-631-9742"
    },
    {
        "userId" : "789",
        "name": "David",
        "phoneNumber": "633-753-1352"
    }
]

var dataLen = data.length;
var people = data;

createKeyValue = ((key, value) => {
    var temp = {};
    temp["value"] = value;
    obj[key] = temp;
});


while (dataLen > 0) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data[0])) {
        switch(key) {
            case 'userId':
                createKeyValue(key, value);
                break;
            case 'name':
                createKeyValue(key, value);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
    
    objectArray.push(obj);
    data.shift();
    dataLen -= 1;

    
}
```

[image]

Comment: `data` is already an array of people objects. What do you want to be different about the new array?

Comment: I don't quite follow your question. Would you be able to edit/update it so you can show what the desired outcome is?

Comment: What should be happening here? At the moment you're adding *the same* object `obj` multiple times to the same array. So you get `objArray` which contains literally the same object (not duplicates) multiple times.

Comment: `obj` is keeping the attributes by reference, not by value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a simple `forEach()` loop to create and push new objects to the `objArray` array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "John",
    "phoneNumber": "123-456-6789"
  },
  {
    "userId": "345",
    "name": "Summer",
    "phoneNumber": "535-631-9742"
  },
  {
    "userId": "789",
    "name": "David",
    "phoneNumber": "633-753-1352"
  }
];

let objArray = [];

data.forEach(person => {
  objArray.push({
    userId: { value: person.userId },
    name: { value: person.name }
  });
});

console.log(objArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by our friends [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) and [Zcoop98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047824/zcoop98), its more appropriate to use forEach function, not map function:

```
data.forEach(elem => {
    objectArray.push({
        userId: { value: elem.userId },
        name: { value: elem.name }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because of a concept in JavaScript (and programming in general) known as "[passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/11047824)."
Objects in JS, instead of being passed as whole groups of data, are passed around as addresses to where that data is stored. This saves a lot of overhead, since objects can become quite large.

In your case however, you're running into one of the ways it can trip you up. Since `obj` is really getting passed by reference instead of value, you're really `.push`ing 3 copies of the same *address* (of `obj`) onto `objectArray` rather than 3 distinct sets of data.

A better approach to this problem would be using a JS Array function called [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This function is probably best explained by MDN:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You can use it on your `data` array like this:

```js
var objectArray = [];
var data = [{
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "John",
    "phoneNumber": "123-456-6789"
  },
  {
    "userId": "345",
    "name": "Summer",
    "phoneNumber": "535-631-9742"
  },
  {
    "userId": "789",
    "name": "David",
    "phoneNumber": "633-753-1352"
  }
]

objectArray = data.map(dataEl => ({
  userId: {
    value: dataEl.userId,
  },
  name: {
    value: dataEl.name,
  },
}));

console.log(objectArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```